# Get users complete profile from Magento Database

Tags: php, android, json, magento

I want to use Magento Login information on another site and also in my android application. Means users have only a one account on a magento based website and he/she can login from android too. I try to get email and password of user but fails.

I'm using php to get user profile from magento.

So any help or guidance please....!

Comment: you have to write a web service for that...

Comment: @RohanPatil i know this, forget about web service, i just want to know   how to get profile user complete profile in php????

Answer (score -1):

Raja ,you can get customer data using soap api of magento,if you don't want  access to magento codes.First create a soap api user in magento.  After that  using below code you get customer details.....

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
for($id=1;;$i++)
{

// $id= customer id
$result = $client->call($session, 'customer.info', '$id');
// result provide one customer data
var_dump($result);
if((isset($result['email'] and $result['email']==null) or (isset($result['email'] and $result['email']==0) )
{
break; //break when email id blank;
}

}

// If you want need the session anymore
$client->endSession($session);
```

Result is an array,result provide this type of data

```
array(
  'customer_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'created_at' => string '2012-03-29 12:37:23' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2012-03-30 12:59:21' (length=19)
  'increment_id' => null
  'store_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'website_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'confirmation' => null
  'created_in' => string 'English' (length=7)
  'default_billing' => null
  'default_shipping' => string '2' (length=1)
  'disable_auto_group_change' => string '0' (length=1)
  'dob' => null
  'email' => string 'john@example.com' (length=16)
  'firstname' => string 'johny' (length=5)
  'gender' => null
  'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'lastname' => string 'doe' (length=3)
  'middlename' => null
  'password_hash' => string 'cccfb3ecf54c9644a34106783148eff2:sp' (length=35)
  'prefix' => null
  'rp_token' => string '15433dd072f1f4e5aae83231b93f72d0' (length=32)
  'rp_token_created_at' => string '2012-03-30 15:10:31' (length=19)
  'suffix' => null
  'taxvat' => null);
```

Comment: Amit Bera, Can we have a small talk? I want to ask something after explaining the complete problem. Thanku

Comment: Raja Zeeshan Ahmed ,yes.

Comment: my skype id is : imzeeshan4u

Comment: i will be avaliable on Monday  at 10am ist

Comment: My skype id is dev.amitbera